# C# equivalent of @ for variables in Go?

Tags: go, identifier

In C# when we want to have a variable with the same name as a keyword, we can prefix the var with @.

```cs
var @type = "Hello, world";
```

Is there anything similar in Go?

Comment: It's a bad idea to do that in C# to begin with. You should use a more descriptive name.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, type was just an example. I recently worked on a project where we had an information model containing an "entity" called a "case"..
Which "forced" me to use "@case" for variable names since else it would "break" the ubiquitous language.

Comment: @Inx51 case as in crate or box? Criminal investigation? Uppercase or lowercase? Patient or trial? The word `case` is not a good choice

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, as in errande, issue or the swedish Ärende.
However.. errand is more like something you need to do, and issue is mainly a "problem".. so none of them really fit the actual meaning of "Ärende". I do agree that a reserved keyword should be avoided to be used as a variable name or as a part of your domain/information model, but as mentioned there are times when it just simply doesnt make sence to name it something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything similar in Golang?

No. You can't redeclare [keywords](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Keywords). `type` is a keyword.

Though some identifiers are [predeclared](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers), they are not keywords, and you can shadow them in a lesser scope. (by the way, **can != should**)

```
var b bool = true

func main() {
    bool := "shadowed bool ident of type string"
    fmt.Println(bool)
}
```

The pattern I see most commonly for variables named "type" is to use `typ` instead.

Note that exported identifiers, e.g. `Type`, are valid.

Comment: To the asker: I would still highly advise against redeclaring anything predeclared; this actually even applies to regular (yours) symbols—except for tricky cases like dealing with reusing of iteration variables in `range` loops. I would recommend to stick to what [this document from the Go code team](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments) suggests.